# What are average partial effects?

Tags: regression, count-data

Does anybody know the meaning of average partial effects? What exactly is it and how can I calculate them? [Here](https://web.archive.org/web/20120418082339/https://www.msu.edu/%7Eec/faculty/wooldridge/current%20research/ape2r8.pdf) is a reference that might help.

Comment: I don't know why anybody downvoted this question, but it may be related to the ease with which Googling `"average partial effects"` (or, better yet, `"average partial effects" definition`) turns up great references.  Nevertheless, a clear answer by an expert would be very welcome here.

Comment: Unfortunately, that link appears to be broken.

Answer (score 21):

I don't think there is a consensus on terminology here, but the following is what I think most people have in mind when someone says "average partial effect" or "average marginal effect".

Suppose, for concreteness, that we are analyzing a population of people. Consider the linear model
$$
 Y = \beta X + U,
$$
where $(Y,X)$ are observed scalar random variables, and $U$ is an unobserved scalar random variable. Suppose that $\beta$ is an unknown constant. Suppose this is a structural model, meaning that it has a causal interpretation. So, if we could pick a person out of the population and increase their value of $X$ by 1 unit, then their value of $Y$ would increase by $\beta$.  Then $\beta$ is called the *marginal* or *causal* effect of $X$ on $Y$.

Now, assuming that $\beta$ is a constant means that no matter which person we pick out of the population, a one unit increase in $X$ has the same effect on $Y$ --- it increases $Y$ by $\beta$. This is clearly restrictive. We can relax this constant effect assumption by supposing that $\beta$ itself a random variable --- each person has a different value of $\beta$. Consequently, there is an entire distribution of marginal effects, the distribution of $\beta$. The mean of this distribution, $E(\beta)$, is called the *average marginal effect* (AME), or average partial effect. If we were to increase everyone's value of $X$ by one unit, then the average change in $Y$ is given by the AME.

Alternatively, consider the nonlinear model
$$
 Y = m(X,U),
$$
where again $(Y,X)$ are scalar observables and $U$ is a scalar unobservable, and $m$ is some unknown function (assume it is differentiable for simplicity). Here the causal/marginal effect of $X$ on $Y$ is $\partial m(x,u)/\partial x$. This value may depend on the value of $U$. Thus, even if we look at people who all have the same observed value of $X$, a small increase in $X$ will not necessarily increase $Y$ by the same amount, because each person may have a different value of $U$. Thus there is a distribution of marginal effects, just as in the linear model above. And, again, we can look at the mean of this distribution:
$$
 E_{U \mid X} \left[ \frac{\partial m(x,U)}{\partial x} \mid X=x \right].
$$
This mean is called the average marginal effect, given $X=x$. If we assume $U$ is independent of $X$, as is sometimes done, then the AME at $X=x$ is simply
$$
 E_{U} \left[ \frac{\partial m(x,U)}{\partial x} \right].
$$
In general, an average marginal effect is just a derivative (or sometimes a finite difference), of a structural function (such as $m(x,u)$ or $\beta x + u$) with respect to an observed variable $X$, averaged over an unobserved variable $U$, perhaps within a particular subgroup of people with $X=x$. The precise form of this effect depends on the specific model under consideration.

Also note that these objects might also be called average treatment effects, especially when considering a finite difference. For example, the difference of the structural function at $X=1$ ('treated') and at $X=0$ ('untreated'), averaged over the unobservables.

Finally, to be clear, note that when I refer to 'distributions' above, I mean distributions *over the population of people*. Each person in the population has a value of $U$, of $X$, and of $Y$. Hence there is a distribution of these values if I look over all people in the population. The thought experiment here is the following. Take all people with $X=x$. Now take one of these people, and increase their $X$ value by a small amount, but keep their $U$ value the same, and we write down the change in their $Y$ value. We do this for each person with $X=x$, and then average the values. This is what it means to average over $U \mid X=x$.

Comment: The answer given by Aelmore is great. Let me only say that maybe the best book on which these things are treated is [Econometric Analysis of Cross Section and Panel Data, Second Edition](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/econometric-analysis-cross-section-and-panel-data-second-edition) by Jeffrey M. Wooldridge. In particular Chapter 2. The book introduces the problem within the context of unobserved heterogeneity, which is crucial topic in modern econometrics.

Comment: Average Marginal Effects (AME) are *not* the same thing as Average Partial Effects (APE). AME =  the marginal contribution of each variable on the scale of the linear predictor). APE = the contribution of each variable on the outcome scale, conditional on the other variables involved in the link function transformation of the linear predictor. Related: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/margins/vignettes/Introduction.html

Answer (score 5):

**Average Partial Effects** (APE) are the contribution of each variable on the outcome scale, *conditional on the other variables involved in the link functio*n transformation of the linear predictor

**Average Marginal Effects** (AME) are the marginal contribution of each variable on the *scale of the linear predictor*.

This [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/margins/vignettes/Introduction.html) from the `margins` package for R is quite useful for understanding.

Comment: Have you seen this distinction been made in other places? I have only found it where you found it in the `margins` package. I am wondering if it is common understanding that there is a difference (Wooldridge for example does not appear to make any distinction).